# Display special character on webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

My database (MySQL) stores data with special character `ï61`. When I try to display the character on my webpage a replacement character is displayed `�61`.

It's probable because my php file is not able to read the object.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Tried encoding/decoding as well.

Comment: The data is likely not encoded as UTF-8, but ISO8859-1 or cp1252. You'll need to figure out which, and then either convert the encoding to UTF-8 or change the content-type header.

Comment: If MySQL has the character in it I assume you have charset and collation as UTF8 there. Have you set the mysql connection to use UTF8 as well?

Comment: What is that table collation is in your database ?

Comment: See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored